# How can I add a column of ones to a normalized array with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

My code is

```
import numpy as np

housing_data = np.loadtxt('Housing.csv', delimiter=',')

x1 = housing_data[:,0]
x2 = housing_data[:,1]
y = housing_data[:,2]

avgX1 = np.mean(x1)
stdX1 = np.std(x1)
normX1 = (x1 - avgX1) / stdX1

avgX2 = np.mean(x2)
stdX2 = np.std(x2)
normX2 = (x2 - avgX2) / stdX2

ones = np.ones((normX2.shape[0], 1))

normalizedX = np.array((ones[0], normX1, normX2))
```

I'm trying to create a new normalized array with the ones in the first column, then the `normX1` and `normX2`. For some reason, my code isn't working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new array, not concatenate to an existing one

Comment: "my code isn't working?" how? are you not getting the result you wanted or are you getting some sort of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue is that you made `ones` 2D where `normX1` and `normX2` are 1D. then when you call `np.array((ones[0], normX1, normX2))` you get the first row of `ones` which is another array of length 1. The mismatch in length between the three args for `np.array` causes it to return a list of the objects instead (a numpy array with `dtype=object`).

I'd just make `ones` big enough to fit all your data in the first place and avoid making one extra array. Then just assign the values of `normX1` and `normX2` to the columns of that array:

```
normalizedX = np.ones((normX2.shape[0], 3))
normalizedX[:,1] = normX1
normalizedX[:,2] = normX2
print(normalizedX)
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. Very helpful

Comment: @Shamoon it would be helpful to the site if you could edit you question now that you know what the actual problem was, so that others with your same problem in the future might have an easier time finding this post. A brief "what I was expecting" vs. "what I got" would go a long way.